# Translating a escapeHtml($message) variable in Magento

Tags: php, magento, translation, translate

I am having trouble translating a string in magento:

"The minimum quantity allowed for purchase is %s."
I have tried different variations of the translation, including %d and *.

So i have tried translating the string in the language file, for Mage_Api and the Mage_Catalog and Mage_CatalogInventory. I have translated tons of string earlier, however this string doesn't want to be translated.

So i want to translate the string manually, however I have run into a problem. I found the following piece of code, where the message is rendered:

```
<?php if ($messages = $this->getMessages()): ?>
        <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>
            <p class="item-msg <?php echo $message['type'] ?>">* <?php
             echo $this->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></p>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

In the rendered HTML, the following is the output:

```
<p class="item-msg error">* The minimum quantity allowed for purchase is 6.</p>
```

So i figure, I have to translate some string within the escapeHtml function. The documentation for the function isn't very helpful ([link](http://doc-magento.com/nav.html?_functions/index.html))

So I am hoping, that someone knows where this string is, so i can overwrite it manually.

Thanks
Patrick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your theme folder create a `locale/[locale]/translate.csv` file.

Example: `app/design/frontend/package/theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

And paste this line:

```
"Mage_CatalogInventory::The minimum quantity allowed for purchase is %s.","TEST The minimum quantity allowed for purchase is %s."
```

Refresh `Translations` cache and you are done. If you are still getting the old string back check the `core_translate` table.

**EDIT**:
String you are looking for is defined in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item` class located in `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/Model/Stock/Item.php`

```
 if ($this->getMinSaleQty() && $qty < $this->getMinSaleQty()) {
            $result->setHasError(true)
                ->setMessage(
                    Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('The minimum quantity allowed for purchase is %s.', $this->getMinSaleQty() * 1)
                )
                ->setErrorCode('qty_min')
                ->setQuoteMessage(Mage::helper('cataloginventory')->__('Some of the products cannot be ordered in requested quantity.'))
                ->setQuoteMessageIndex('qty');
            return $result;
        }
```

Comment: Hi Reindex, thanks for your answer. I will be trying this today, and will ofcourse accept this, if it works!